# Goal seek Excel in Qlik Sense

Tags: excel, qliksense

First, apologies for my basic English.

**Is there a function in QlikView that performs like Goal Seek in Excel?**

The idea is get a value from a cell, say `$F$12`, and find the cells  **that need to be changed in order to get that result**,  as you can see in [**this image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cy5I.jpg). I'm looking for function similar in Qlik Sense. Anyone know how to do this? Or even if it is possible at all?

Thanks!